# Publish and Subscribe to Comet Server in Java-application

Tags: java, comet, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to implement clients that can subscribe and publish to the Comet Server, from within a Java application?

Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to build subscribing clients in Java. Refer to the [CometD](http://cometd.org/) homepage, they have a robust server and a Java API. As far as server solutions go, check out Tomcat and Glassfish. You can also check out [StreamHub](http://www.stream-hub.com/).

What do you mean by publish to the Comet server? As this is not a typical scenario in a server push architecture.

Comment: The architecture I am implementing is that I have a core engine that generates events, and I would like other client applications to subscribe to them in real-time. These clients may be other java applications or may be at the browser level. So I am trying to leverage the pub/sub in Comet, so that clients can be pushed events without having to poll. (Is there a better, more easier way? Are there any online tutes you could recommend to implement this sort of architecture?) Thnx.

Comment: Ok, we are talking about the same thing then. A central message authority and several subscribers (of different types, some Java, some browser). Great use scenario for Comet. I am not aware of any tutorial specific to your case but the CometD distribution does come with demo code highlighting how to use the API's. Also see this link, it may help some: http://cometd.org/documentation/howtos/primer.